# Autowire doesn't seems to be working

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-3.4

**[PROBLEM]**

I'm on Symfony 3.4, and I got some issues with the way services are handled now. Even though it's working, I'm forced to use the old way, which is a problem.

I'm using [DataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/data_transformers.html) on a form, but for some reasons, I got the following error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\VarianteEscalierOptGc\VarianteEscalierOptGcEditPoteauType::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\VarianteEscalierTransformer, none given

As written in the doc:

> That's it! As long as you're using autowire and autoconfigure, Symfony will automatically know to pass your TaskType an instance of the IssueToNumberTransformer.

Which is my case, but still got the error.

Also, if someone can hint me how to correctly update my services below, that would be great.

**[FILES]**

<kbd>**FormType**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('varianteEscalier', HiddenType::class, array('data'=>$options['data']->getVarianteEscalier()->getId()))
            ->add('gardecorpsOption', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:GardecorpsOption',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder("gco")
                              ->where("gco.type='poteau'")
                              ->andWhere("gco.actif=1");
                },
            ))
            ->add('quantite');
    $builder->get('varianteEscalier')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
}
```

<kbd>**Transformer.php**</kbd>

```
class VarianteEscalierTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em=$em;
    }

    /**
     * @param  Object|null $entity
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($entity) {
        if(null === $entity) {
            return "";
        }

        return $entity->getId();
    }

    /**
     * @param $entityId
     * @return VarianteEscalier|null
     */
    public function reverseTransform($entityId) {
        if(!$entityId) {
            return null;
        }
        $entity=$this->em->getRepository(VarianteEscalier::class)->findOneBy(array('id'=>$entityId));
        if($entity === null) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('VarianteEScalier avec l\'id '.$entityId.' n\'existe pas!'));
        }

        /** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */
        return $entity;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
    listener.projet:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\ProjetListener
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true }
    listener.variante:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\VarianteListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true }
    service.upload:
        public: true
        class: AppBundle\Service\UploadService
        arguments:
            $dirPicto: '%dir_picto%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing service discovery section, so right after `_default` you forgot this

```
_defaults:
  ...

  App\: #You might need to change this to the correct namespace
    resource: '../src/*'
```

Take a look https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#step-4-auto-registering-services

Comment: Thanks. I understand now why I couldn't use services as I should. I got another error, my function `transform()` have this error: `Call to a member function getId() on integer`. Got an idea?

Comment: Nvm, found why... I was using `getId()` in my form builder while I shouldn't.