# Symfony 3.4 - Auto wire of service not working in method

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm relatively new to Symfony, and I'm having trouble some trouble.
I'm trying to type hint a custom RequestValidator class in the method being called when the endpoint is called.

Using Symfony 3.4

However, I am getting the following error:

> Controller "ApiBundle\Endpoints\Healthcheck\v1\Index::check()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

Here is my setup:

**services.yml file**

```
...
        _defaults:
           autowire: true
           autoconfigure: true

...
```

**routing.yml**

```
api.Healthcheck:
path: /healthcheck
controller: ApiBundle\Endpoints\Healthcheck\v1\Index::check
defaults: { _format: json }
methods:
    - GET
```

And then - inside the Index class, I have the following:

```
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\Endpoints\Healthcheck\v1;

use ApiBundle\Responses\ApiResponse;


class Index extends ApiResponse
{

      public function check(HealthcheckRequest $request) {
        var_dump($request);die;
    }

}
```

When I do debug:autowiring I see my HealthcheckRequest in the list.

Further, when I do the same and try type-hint in the constructor of the Index class, it all works.

And finally, if I try and type hint the Symfony/HttpFoundation/Request, inside the check() method, it instantiates it correctly.

In summary:

Not working :

- check(HealthcheckRequest $request)

Working:

- __construct(HealtcheckRequest $request)
- check(SymfonyRequest $request)

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a use statement for HealtheckRequest in your actual code?

Comment: And is ApiResponse just a poorly named controller base class?  Action injection is only going to work with controller actions.  Unless this health bundle does some very interesting stuff.

Comment: HealtcheckRequest is in the same namespace, but I tried with and without the use statement, same result.

Comment: ApiResponse is a base class that only contains jsonResponse() method that returns an instance of a ApiJsonResponse class which is a "fluent" wrapper around the JsonResponse class that Symfony Provides allowing for something like
$this->jsonResponse()->addResponseData()->setResponseCode()->getResponse() inside the Index class. 

It does not extend the Controler class of Symfony.

Comment: Have you loocked at this question? [Autowire doesn't seems to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214150/autowire-doesnt-seems-to-be-working)

Comment: @user3237838 You need to go back and see what is calling the check method.  There is nothing magical or "auto" going on here.  Whoever is calling check need to pass the argument.

Comment: @Preciel Saw it now but I already have the resource: part in services.yml and the service is available in the debug:autowire list as I posted

Comment: @Cerad check() is being as the "relevant" method for the API endpoint as listed in the routes.yml file - which is available in my original post. Not sure why it is working in the constructor and why the Symfony class is being auto-wired in check(), but my class isn't

Comment: So just to be clear, HealthCheckRequest extends the Symfony Request object and you tweaked the create method to return a HealthCheckRequest object instead of a Request object?  Is this your own code or some sort of third party library?

Comment: If you look at RequestValueResolver you will see that it is hardcoded to the Symfony Request class.  So even if you were making your own request it won't get injected.  Symfony really wants you to use it's request class.  If you tried hard enough you could probably make your own resolver class and inject it.  No idea how.  Might also consider injecting the RequestStack and pulling the request from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of services.yaml already in Symfony 4, but introduced in version 3.3, so this might help:

```
# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class

ApiBundle\Endpoints\:
    resource: '../../Endpoints/*'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```